# How to store Javascript value in mysql database in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mysql

I have a text value of javascript and I want to store this value in a mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

Java script is a client side language , so it cant store values directly to mysql database
but you can call a server side script (php ,asp .... ) providing it with the value as a parameter.
you can either load the new script as a new page or use ajax.

Comment: ajax code is totally un-related to your problem , it is just a way to call the server side script that will do the database work , any way for ajax the w3schools tutorial is good and you might also want to look at the mysql/php tutorial.
and you really should start accepting answers to encourage more people to answer yours.

w3schools ajax tutorial : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp
mysql tutorial : http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_intro.asp

hope that helps.